# UFW allow rules not working?

Tags: firewall, ufw, gateway

I have a cluster configuration with one machine that functions as a gateway (call it `master`) and several machines that only have private IP addresses (call them `s01` to `s09`).

I recently installed `ufw` on `master` and noticed that the machines behind the Gateway were no longer able to access the outside internet (`wget google.com` fails).

I looked in my logs and saw lines that looked like this.

```
 [609940.531858] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT=eth0 MAC=00:25:90:0c:e0:5b:00:25:90:32:3c:9e:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.178 DST=172.217.6.78 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=58107 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59584 DPT=80 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x9
```

I added the following rule to `ufw`.

```
ufw allow from 192.168.0.178
ufw reload
```

Here's the output of `ufw` status.

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.0.178
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Unfortunately, `wget` still fails, and I still see more `UFW BLOCK` lines like the above in my logs.

How do I correctly configure ufw to allow outbound traffic from the hosts behind my gateway?

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation, it turns out that UFW defaults to rejecting forwarding requests. One potential solution was to edit `/etc/default/ufw` and set `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`, but this seemed insecure.

Instead, I added the following rules to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`.

```
# Eth0 is public, Eth1 is private.
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer just helped me a lot. Maybe saved hours.

Comment: Glad it's still useful after 4.5 years!